# How can I improve the Setting Options interface of my application with a List View?

Tags: android, ios, listview, flutter

I'm new using flutters, I've made a Setting Options interface but I think it could be developed in a better way.

I used Rows and Columns in the development, but I think it can be done with a list view -in case you want to connect it with Firebase or another type of Data Link

```
class datosUsuarios extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: 2),
      ),*/
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Divider( height: 25,color: Colors.grey,),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.blueAccent,),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Nombre:"),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Your Name",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),)
            ],
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5),
          Divider( height: 25,color: Colors.grey,),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Icon(Icons.mail,color: Colors.blueAccent),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Correo"),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Jefferson@mpytx.com",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),)
            ],
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5),
          Divider( height: 25,color: Colors.grey,),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Icon(Icons.phone,color: Colors.blueAccent),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Telefono"),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("+52 9802638955",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),)
            ],
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5),
          Divider( height: 25,color: Colors.grey,),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Icon(Icons.info,color: Colors.blueAccent),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Version"),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text("Beta 0.1.0.",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),)
            ],
          ),
          //SizedBox(width: 5),
          Divider( height: 25,color: Colors.grey,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code returns a Container with the elements one under another and separate, I would like to know if there is any other way to do this. Thanks.
The results its is
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCCWP.jpg[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qZ4n.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use simple model like this:

```
class SettingsItem {
  Icon icon;
  String label;
  String content;

  SettingsItem({
    @required this.icon,
    @required this.label,
    @required this.content,
  });
}
```

Mock some data:

```
 List<SettingsItem> _settings = [
    SettingsItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Nombre', content: 'Jefferson'),
    SettingsItem(icon: Icon(Icons.mail), label: 'Correo', content: 'jefferson@gmail.com'),
    SettingsItem(icon: Icon(Icons.phone), label: 'Telefono', content: '+51 9 999 999 9999'),
  ];
```

And use `ListView` with `ListTile` and `ListTile.divideTiles`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Settings'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: ListTile.divideTiles(
          color: Colors.grey,
          tiles: _settings.map((setting) {
            return ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: setting.icon,
              title: Text(setting.label),
              subtitle: Text(setting.content),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the `ListTile` has a `title` and `subtitle` you can use. Also the `ListTile` provides you an `onTap` gesture with a ripple effect under the hood. The final result will be like this:

[image]